# create generic exe for all processor types in windows using gcc

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, gcc, cross-compiling

I want to create generic exe for all processor types in windows using gcc. 
Today, when I generate an exe using gcc in Windows 7 with intel i7 processor, it doesn't work on Windows 7 with AMD A6 processor. I gave the following command for compilation:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -I. strcmp.cpp -L. -lstdc++ -o strcmp.exe
```

I tried giving even `-march=x86-64` option for generating the executable. But each time, it works on the PC it got generated but not on PC with AMD processor.

What is the flag in gcc I need to provide to create a binary for all the processors?

Not working as in: 
There is no output. Exe gracefully closes. No crash, nothing. Since, it's and exe I am running, which is not throwing even the first std::cout, it's getting difficult to debug.

Code is very simple hello world program with std::cout.

compiler used: gcc 4.8.1 in Windows 7.

Sample code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str1[] = "BRAND   ";
    char str2[] = "brand   ";
    char str3[] = "BRANd";
    char str4[] = "BRaND";

    char strx1[] = "Copper";
    char strx2[] = "COPPER  ";
    char strx3[] = "COPper";
    char strx4[] = "CoPPer  ";
    bool result;

    std::cout << "Strings: " << "str1: " << str1 << ", str2: " << str2 << std::endl;
    result = strncmp(str1, sizeof(str1), str2, sizeof(str2));
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << ", should be true" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Strings: " << "str3: " << str3 << ", str2: " << str2 << std::endl;
    result = strncmp(str3, sizeof(str3), str2, sizeof(str2));
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << ", should be true" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Strings: " << "str4: " << str4 << ", str2: " << str2 << std::endl;
    result = strncmp(str4, sizeof(str4), str2, sizeof(str2));
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << ", should be true" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Strings: " << "str1: " << str1 << ", str4: " << str4 << std::endl;
    result = strncmp(str1, sizeof(str1), str4, sizeof(str4));
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << ", should be true" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Strings: " << "str1: " << str1 << ", strx2: " << strx2 << std::endl;
    result = strncmp(str1, sizeof(str1), strx2, sizeof(strx2));
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << ", should be false" << std::endl;

    std::cout  << std::endl  << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it crash or calculate an incorrect result? Or does it fail in some other way? Also, if you know which lines in code are problematic, please add them to the question.

Comment: Why downvotes? _"What is the flag in gcc I need to provide to create a binary for all the processors?"_ Is a valid question (even if no such option exists. Then this is the answer).

Comment: There is no output. Exe gracefully closes. No crash, nothing. Since, it's and exe I am running, which is not throwing even the first std::cout, it's getting difficult to debug.

Comment: It might help if you posted a cut-down source file that does something on the one machine and not the other, so people can try it for themselves.

Comment: Post the source you're using. There's no issue with the options you've provided that would make a difference on the CPU it will run on, and the CPU your compiler is executing on doesn't make a difference either, so you're doing something more than what you say.

Comment: I bet libstdc++ is not available on the system with the AMD CPU.

Comment: Added sample code and the compiler command been given. The exe generated on i7 processor works perfectly fine on Windows VM on the same i7 machine. But it doesn't show any output on AMD processor.

Comment: "all the processors"?! @πάνταῥεῖ Why _not_ downvotes? This is woefully underspecified. He doesn't even list which processors he wants to target, instead assuming for some reason that he can just write for "any computer" with the same machine code. (Handily, of course, the most popular chipsets used on Windows machines are often compatible thanks to x86/x86_64 friendliness. But that doesn't matter. The detail needs specifying, not assuming.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Underspecification is actually a good point.

Comment: I added all the lib*.dll files from bin directory of gcc into the working directory including libstdc++6.dll. But no result. Whereas if I compile the code in AMD, the exe works just fine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [Compile all the processors](http://i.imgur.com/d1vrCjN.jpg).  For Sunil: there are many, many kinds of processor.  "I want to run on all processors" is not a reasonable request.  I could guess that you mean "x86 compatible processors since the pentium, and amd64 64 bit variations of same".  Not, for example, ia-64, a 286, or a powerPC?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you for pointing it out. Yes, I meant processors where Windows 7 can be installed ie intel-64 processors and amd-64 processors.

Comment: @SunilVerma Well, if you mean by intel-64 the IA64 architecture a.k.a. Itanium, it's largely incompatible with x86 and/or x86_64 a.k.a. amd64. In general, aside from Itanium, even the Intel 64-bit Core processors are considered amd64 or x86_64. And, if you want to include e.g. older pentiums, and other i686 processors as well, that will limit you to a 32-bit build, not a 64-bit one...